# Listing non-admin accounts in OS X with dscl

Tags: macos, bash, awk, dscl

Trying to write a Bash script that will pull all non-admin accounts into an array to which I can then remove the home directories `rm -rf /Users/"$USER"` and also delete the Sys Pref user `dscl . -delete /Users/"$USER"`.

I can pull all admins with `dscl . -read /Groups/admin GroupMembership | grep "$USER" | awk '{ print $3 }'` but cannot figure out the command to pull non-admins.

Any help would be amazing!

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to go about this differently.

1. Use dscl to read all users in the directory and store results

   `dscl . list /Users`
2. Use your current dscl call to return all admin users.  Store results separate from step one
3. Loop through results from step 1 and, on each pass, loop through results from step 2.
4. if the user of the main loop does not match any of admin users, execute your deletions against that user.

Comment: Sure thing.  Let me know if you hit any roadblocks.